# Issue converting the date timezone

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to convert the date and time. I tried with this code but it is not working properly. The output is empty. Kindly make the correction.

I need to show the date and time of Pakistan timezone.

```
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi"); 
$date = "25-03-2019 07:48 AM"; 
echo date($date,"d-m-Y H:i A");
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide your code, it is missing :)

Comment: You forgot to post your query. Please show the query which is behind `$row['createdon'];` as that's where the logic will go.

Comment: Well... it depends on what the data inside `$row['createdon']` looks like.

Comment: share your `$row['createdon']` here

Comment: what output you currently got?

Comment: your date is in string format already

Answer (score 0):

> `date()` first param should be `format` and second should be `unix-timestamp`

```
<?php 
foreach($records as $row){ 

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi"); 

    $date = strtotime($row['createdon']); //it must be unix-timestamp if not then do with strtotime();
    echo date("d-m-Y H:i A",$data);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi"); 
$date = "25-03-2019 07:48 AM"; 
echo date("d-m-Y H:i A", strtotime($date); // but this date should come from your database
?>
```

**You can try this code.**